# How to Handle Special characters and geometric datatypes in talend

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I came across the below 2 errors while migrating Postgres DB to Snowflake through Talend. And I am doing a dynamic full load to Snowflake.

- There are a few Tables and Columns having Special characters for which I am getting the below error: org.apache.Avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: conces_$
- And few Tables have Geometric data types like Polygone. Talend is not able to read those tables.

Please let me know if you have any alternative way of moving these.

**NOTE:**

- I have Read-only access to Postgres through Talend
- I have read and write access to Snowflake through Talend
- I don't have direct access to these databases as they are Prod DB's.

Comment: Hi - your first issue is probably a mismatch between the Codepages set for your Source, Talend and Target. For your 2nd issue: what is the error message when Talend reads tables that have these data types? What are you planning to do with this data e.g. write it directly to a Snowflake (what Snowflake datatype)? Transform it in some way?

Comment: I have fixed the second one there was relevant data type in snowflake. Now I tried to debug the first error, the thing is few field names have special characters and spaces. I tried to get the schema using metadata for the table it did replace those with underscores but I can't pull the data from the source